# Как с помощью seaborn (catplot или barplot) на одном графике отобразить значение нескольких?

Tags: python, seaborn

Как с помощью seaborn (catplot или barplot) на одном графике отобразить значение нескольких столбцов DataFrame?
Ниже приведен не рабочий код. Он корректно отображает график только для одного столбца, а нужно чтобы отображал несколько столбцов, как приведено ниже на примере.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns 

sns.set()



c1 = [0.3, 0.5, 0, 0.9] 
c2 = [0.7, 0, 0.1, 0]
dct = {'c1':c1, 'c2':c2}
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
print(df)

sns.barplot(x=df.index.values, y='c1', data=df)
#sns.barplot(x=df.index.values, y='c2', data=df)
plt.show()
```

Желаемый график

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерный вариант. Наверное, можно ещё как-то красивше, но пока не придумал:

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(level=1)
df1.columns = ['c', 'value']
sns.barplot(x=df1.index.values, y='value', hue='c', data=df1)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns-plot]

То есть нужно сделать такой `DataFrame`, чтобы можно было через `hue` разделить столбцы на `c1` и `c2`. В `df1` у меня при этом получилось следующее:

```
    c   value
0   c1  0.3
0   c2  0.7
1   c1  0.5
1   c2  0.0
2   c1  0.0
2   c2  0.1
3   c1  0.9
3   c2  0.0
```

Comment: Я думал об этом варианте, но он мне нравился. Думал он не правильный :(

Comment: @YuriyTigiev Наверняка можно ещё через `pivot` как-то, но я в нём не силён, надо MaxU на помощь звать )

Answer (score 1):

Кстати, если `Seaborn` - это не обязательное условие, то всё вообще просто:

```
df.plot(kind='bar');
# или df.plot.bar();
```

[image: df-plot]